# Opendj HostName changes

Tags: opendj

We are using OpenDj 2.4.6 Version. We are going to changes the host name in PRODUCTION environment, which is in Replication Environment.

How will we change the host names?

Where will we need to make the required change(s)? Please be helpful by providing us any suggestions or answers.

Comment: Hi , Can you please share me to above required information  ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

When you move an OpenDJ directory server replica from one host to another, the data is portable but the server keys might not be portable, and the replication configuration is not portable.

Although you ask about 2.4, the 2.6 *Administration Guide* chapter describing the procedures for [*Moving Servers*](https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/opendj/2.6/admin-guide/chap-mv-servers) still applies.

There's also [an article](https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/knowledge/kb/article/a87750034) in the ForgeRock knowledge base that specifically covers changing hostnames.